# Issues with Azure policy summary and the count

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-policy

I am querying azure policy information using summary and my objective is to correlate the numbers displayed on the portal using powershell so that I can perform some analysis on the numbers. Its been a frustrating experience so far.

Reference sources
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.policyinsights/get-azpolicystate?view=azps-10.4.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azpolicyassignment?view=azps-10.4.1&viewFallbackFrom=azps-6.6.0

What am i trying to achieve ?

Get the same numbers in terms of non-compliant resources as shown on the Azure portal
Then filter by specific resource groups, whilst I can filter by specific resource groups, if the numbers do not match, its an issue. When I examine the spreadsheet I can see duplicates.

[image]

What have I done ?

```
Get-AzPolicyState -ManagementGroupName 'xxx' -Filter " ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant' and PolicySetDefinitionName eq 'xx'"
```

I have filtered it based on the `PolicySetDefinitionName` thinking that would make the numbers tally up. If the numbers do not tally up, it skews my report as if one goes onto the portal, the numbers will not match.

A breakdown using the below is very close, but has some extra values in where, so not sure what to do.

```
Get-AzPolicyState -ManagementGroupName 'xx' -Filter " ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant' and PolicySetDefinitionName eq 'xx' and PolicyDefinitionAction eq 'audit'" -Apply "groupby((PolicyAssignmentId, PolicySetDefinitionId, PolicyDefinitionReferenceId, PolicyDefinitionId), aggregate(`$count as NumStates))" -OrderBy "NumStates desc" -Top 1000
```

Comment: What is the exact issue with the second PowerShell query? @learner

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach using the PowerShell command is accurate, but you need to make a few modifications to identify and delete duplicates.

*Note:* Ensure that the `PowerShell` output is filtered using the same criteria as the portal results. You need to also consider for probable data duplication.

After made a few changes, your script should looks like below.

Here I have tried to filter out under subscription level as management group access is restricted in my environment. You can replace the `subscriptionID` with the management group name along with the property `-ManagementGroupName`.

```
$policysetdef = "xxx"
$Action = 'audit'
$policyState = Get-AzPolicyState -SubscriptionId "xxxx" `
    -Filter "ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant' and PolicySetDefinitionName eq '$policysetdef' and PolicyDefinitionAction eq '$Action'"
$uniquestates = $policyState | unique
$groupedPolicyStateinfo = $uniquestates | Group-Object -Property @{Name='PolicySetDefinitionId';Expression={$_.PolicySetDefinitionId}} `
    -AsHashTable | Measure-Object -Property Value -Sum | Sort-Object -Descending count | Select-Object -First 1000
Write-Output $groupedPolicyStateinfo
```

*Output:*

[image]

Comment: Please help clarify, when you look under policies from the portal, then under compliance, I have got some compliance initiatives for example `CIS Microsoft Azure Foundations Benchmark v1.4.0` how can I be sure that it is filtering based on this initiative ? I have tried to use the `PolicySetDefinitionName` here, which gives me an ID rather than the name. I also get the error `Group-Object : The Name key is not valid.`

Comment: You mean `Get-AzPolicyState` is throwing an error? @learner

Comment: Its the group-object doesn't like something about it. ? @jahnavi

Comment: If possible, can you let me know the whole error to figure out the issue. @learner

Comment: $policysetdef = 'xxxxxxx' 
$Action = 'audit'
$policyState = Get-AzPolicyState -ManagementGroupName 'man-group' -Filter "ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant' and PolicySetDefinitionName eq '$policysetdef' `
     and PolicyDefinitionAction eq '$Action'" $uniquestates = $policyState | unique $groupedPolicyStateinfo = $uniquestates     `
     | Group-Object -Property @{Name='PolicySetDefinitionId';Expression={$_.PolicySetDefinitionId}}  -AsHashTable | `
     Measure-Object -Property Value -Sum | Sort-Object -Descending count | Select-Object -First 1000
Write-Output $groupedPolicyStateinfo

Comment: I get the error `Get-AzPolicyState : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.PolicyInsights.Models.PolicyState'.
At line:1 char:16`

Comment: when I run it from ps ISE.. I get  the error below. I am running using powershell v5. I am not sure why its not working for me.

`Group-Object : The Name key is not valid.
At line:8 char:43
+ ... questates | Group-Object -Property @{Name='PolicySetDefinitionId';Exp ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Group-Object], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyIllegal,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupObjectCommand`